# No output for C++ GPIO code for Beaglebone Black

Tags: gpio, beaglebone-black, c++

Could anyone tell what could possibly be wrong in the following C++ code for enabling and setting pin no 49 (p9_23). I am directly checking the output on multimeter.

````
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using std::ofstream;
using namespace std;

#define gpio_path "/sys/class/gpio/"

enum GPIO_DIRECTION {INPUT, OUTPUT};
enum GPIO_SETVALUE {LOW=0, HIGH=1};

class GPIO {
  private: 
    int number, i;
    string gpio_dir, name;
    string filename, a, c, j, b, path, dir, val, value, high, low, input, output;

  public:
    GPIO(int number);
    virtual int setdirection(GPIO_DIRECTION dir);
    virtual int setpin(GPIO_SETVALUE val);
    virtual int writein(string filename, string  value);
    virtual int  write(string filename, int  value); 
    virtual ~GPIO();
};    

GPIO::GPIO(int number) {
  this->number = number;
  std::ostringstream s;
  s << "gpio" << number;
  //again converting stream to string 
  this->name=string(s.str());
  j=string(gpio_path);
  this->path=j + this->name;
  write("j/export", this->number);
}

int GPIO::setdirection(GPIO_DIRECTION dir) {
  switch(dir) {
  case INPUT:
    return this->writein("path/direction", "in");
    break;
  case OUTPUT: 
    return this->writein("path/direction", "out");
    break;
  }
  return -1;
}

int GPIO::setpin(GPIO_SETVALUE val) {
  switch(val) {
  case HIGH:
    return this->writein("path/value", "1");
    break;
  case LOW:
    return this->writein("path/value", "0");
    break;
  }       
  return -1;
}

int  GPIO::write(string filename, int value) {
  ofstream ds;
  ds.open(filename.c_str());
  ds<<value;
  ds.close();
  return 0;
}

int GPIO::writein(string filename, string value) {
  ofstream ls;
  ls.open(filename.c_str());
  ls << value;
  ls.close();
  return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: Try to set the pins from putty terminal commands and then proceed in c++

Comment: using command line on the beaglebone i'm not getting the output. problem i guess is in the file handling.

Comment: Are you trying to access GPIO-1, bit 17? Have you verified that the pin-mux is set to allow that signal as output on that pin? You would likely need to load a .dtob file  in order to tell Linux that you need access to that pin (you are running Linux, right?), and to have the kernel set the pin-mux and the mode for you.

Comment: you mean to say i need to do some tweaking with the overlays? i have to check, as I am still new to overlays. what exactly does an overlay do?

Comment: The device tree overlay is relatively new, and it was added because a pin on many MCUs have multiple functions. The BBB pins typically have 8 functions assigned, and the GPIO is usually number 7. Also, a pin could be input or output, and you may or may not want to enable the internal pull-up / pull-down resistors. Since user-mode programs don't have permission to access the pin-mux control registers, the device-tree overlays were added to allow the kernel to set things up for you. It's a pain in the neck, but much easier than recompiling the kernel to set the pin-mux for your application.

Comment: Some links: https://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/petazzoni-device-tree-dummies.pdf

Comment: http://www.devicetree.org/

Comment: You might try constructing the sysfs file names in a more traditional way and testing with shell commands like echo first.  But beyond that, this is a long abandonded debugging question, voting to close.